# Communication among pods not working after exposing as service

Tags: kubernetes

I have set up a kubernetes Cluster manually. The cluster is healthy. The nodes are up. The pods and services are also created and running.

I have a web pod which is a python flask application. A db-pod which is redis. Exposed redis as a service to be accessible from python. Exposed web pod as external service also. The external service is running in 31727 port.

When i access the web application through browser, it reports redis host is not accessible.

The application works well when deployed in a kubernetes cluster created using kubeadm/kops.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like kube-proxy or overlay networking issue at first glance. Are you sure kube-proxy is launched on nodes and you have a working overlay ? Can you ping pods directly on a pod-to-pod basis ?

Update: as your pod-to-pod connectivity is down, you need to look into your flannel configuration, and make sure it works fine, as well as make sure pods are started with flannel networking (ie. via CNI) rather than local docker0 interfaces network.

Comment: I have used Flanneld as the overlay network solution. Flanneld is running master as well as the nodes. Kube-Proxy also has no errors in the logs.

Comment: you have not answered the last part of my question

Comment: I am not able to ping pods directly on a pod-to-pod.